# What is the right way to mimic interface in Python with AbstractClass and type hinting

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, type-hinting

I need to write an abstract class which will act like an driver to "something external".

```py
# ./base.py
import typing as t
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class DefaultClass: pass

MyType = t.TypeVar("MyType", bound=DefaultClass)

class Driver(ABC):
    def __init__(self, return_class: t.Type[MyType]):
        self.return_class = return_class

    def driver_call(self, param: str) -> MyType:
       return self._driver_call(param)

    @abstractmethod
    def _driver_call(self, param: str) -> MyType:
       raise NotImplementedError()
```

But here I struggle. Let me try to inherit from this class:

```py
# ./mydriver.py
from base import Driver, DefaultClass


class CustomDriver(Driver):
    def __init__(self, return_class):
        super().__init__(return_class)
    
    def _driver_call(self, param: str) -> ???:
       return self.return_class(param)


# Usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    class CustomClass(DefaultClass):
        def __init__(self, name: str):
            self.name = name


    cd = CustomDriver(CustomClass)
    instance = cd.driver_call("some_string")
```

I struggle with next point:

- From PyCharm and type hinting point of view what should I set as return type in `_driver_call()` to make it clear that it should return instance of class which is set in `self.return_class`

I've read about generics type etc, but currently I can't map info what i read with my goal to make "interface" for driver.

OR may be I am so wrong that there is absolutely another way to do it?

Comment: Not sure but you could look at Python [protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)

Comment: Additionally, I recommend taking a look at Fluent Python (2nd ed.), which has a lot of good info on interfaces and protocols with type hinting in Python

Comment: skimmed qu, but try `class Driver(ABC, Generic[MyType]):` and `class CustomDriver(Driver[MyType]):` then return `MyType`. Note that you don't want `t.type[MyType]`, you want `Callable[[str], MyType]`. Side note: `_driver_call` is redundant afaict, just use `driver_call`

Answer (score 1):

You did not give enough context to provide an unambiguous recommendation, but I'll give it a shot.

If that "something external" being driven by your `Driver` subclasses indeed always inherits from the same base class, there is no need for `typing.Protocol` here since we have nominal subtyping to guide us.

I agree with @joel that this screams `typing.Generic` and that `_driver_call` is redundant (as it appears from your example right now).

The nice thing about abstract base classes is that you typically don't need to write an `__init__` method. You can just lay out the attributes and annotate them with their expected types.

I am assuming you know the concrete `CustomClass` you want to drive with a `Driver` subclass in advance. A also assume that not all subclasses of `DefaultClass` will have the same constructor interface, so your abstract `Driver` cannot mirror the constructor's signature.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="DefaultClass")


# External:
class DefaultClass:
    pass


# Generic abstract base class:
class Driver(ABC, Generic[T]):
    return_class: type[T]

    @abstractmethod
    def driver_call(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
        ...


# External, but with a specific init signature:
class CustomClass(DefaultClass):
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name


# Specification:
class CustomDriver(Driver[CustomClass]):
    def __init__(self, return_class: type[CustomClass]) -> None:
        self.return_class = return_class

    def driver_call(self, param: str) -> CustomClass:
        return self.return_class(param)
```

If you want your `CustomDriver` to *also* be generic over `T`, you'll need to be careful with the constructor signature because it seems you assume you'll always be able to initialize a `DefaultClass` subtype with just a `str` argument. Maybe that is what @joel meant with his comment about typing it with `Callable`. In that case it would look more like this:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", bound="DefaultClass")


class DefaultClass:
    pass


class Driver(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def driver_call(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
        ...


class CustomDriver(Driver[T]):
    def __init__(self, cls_constructor: Callable[[str], T]) -> None:
        self.cls_constructor = cls_constructor

    def driver_call(self, param: str) -> T:
        return self.cls_constructor(param)


class CustomClass(DefaultClass):
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
```

Both version work and are type safe with this usage:

```py
cd = CustomDriver(CustomClass)
instance = cd.driver_call("some_string")
```

A class is also a callable returning an instance of itself, which is why the `Callable[..., T]` notation is technically more general than `type[T]`.

As you noticed, there are a lot of assumptions here. I hope you see that you need to be clearer in your questions, so that others need to do less guessing about what it is you actually want. If you care to elaborate further and provide more context in your original post, I can try and amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: why the `*args: Any, **kwargs: Any`? that invites all manner of runtime type errors

Comment: @joel That is just a placeholder because OP did not give any information about whether or not the constructors of all `DefaultClass` instances will indeed have the same signature. If they do or if you know in advance what kind of signatures should be possible, that of course needs to be made more specific. But it is good that you pointed that out. I tried to give as general an answer as I could from the limited information given to us. I mean OP _literally_ called it "something external"...

Comment: thank you for your answer. I guess my goal to make such astract class so Pycharm will guide an user who decided to inherit from Driver how to create it properly. In you first case cls.return_class: type[Generic] do nothing for hinting while bulding CustomDriver. I can place any type  in init and get no warning from IDE. (may be it not even possible I dont know - iam here trying to know). And second question is about how to force(with type hinting + abstratcmethod) to build method that return isntance of cls.return_class and not allow(again with ide warning) return any type he wants